# Moving Wiki Pages from One Sharepoint site to another

Tags: sharepoint, copy, wiki, move

I have site level admin access on an old sharepoint site and a new sharepoint site.

I have tried the following -

I Have copied the Wiki pages using the Sharepoint Designer 2010, But for some reason the references in those wiki pages go for a toss.

I Have tried exporting the library to an MS Access Database and importing it to the new site. Still doesnt work.

**Could someone let me know how I can copy/move the wiki pages from the old site to the new site?**

Answer (score 5):

There are number of way to copy data between lists and libraries:
1) Export\import using stsadm:
http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/

2) Using list template or spreadsheet:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-lists-HA001154562.aspx

3) Programmatically:
http://www.spsamples.com/2011/07/moving-sharepoint-list-items-to-archive.html

Comment: Thanks on the Advice. Could you let me know if we migrate the pages, the references will remain intact as well?

Comment: I guess second method will not replace links, using Third method - you can try (http://ruudheemskerk.net/archive/2009/05/29/copy-or-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-spexport-and-spimport.aspx - see replace backlinks topic), don't know about the first.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [SPDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427553.aspx) API. You can export the entire wiki page library (list) and import it to other site or site collection, or you can just export/import selected pages (list items).

I'm afraid that the OOTB SP tools (stsadm and PS cmdlets) let you export only an entire web site. To export just a part of the site - a wiki page library in your case - you'd have to code it using the SP API. It's not complicated, though.

Comment: Thank You. I do not have access to the server where the Sharepoint foundation is installed. Will need to request the Farm admin to grant me access.

Comment: I'm afraid that you'd need the access to the server. You could make use of the export/import functionality remotely by SOAP WS but again, it is limited to the entire web site, [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453426(v=office.12).aspx).

You usually use your own SP server for the development. It can be installed even on Windows 7 for this purpose. Admins usually don't like to give access to their servers permanently or for a long time. You would need the server access just for testing.